# 'body' width and height changing depending on positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple html page like this:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
        html,body
        {
            min-width:100%;
            min-height:100%;
                    position:relative;
        }

        img
        {
           width:200px;
           height:200px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="image.png" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Now when I load the page the width and height of the 'body' must be atleast the full width and full height of the browser window right? But when I retrieve the body's height using jquery like `$('body').height()`it returns 200px which is the height of the image inside the body and not the height of the window which is actually much taller than the image.

But when I change html and body's positioning to absolute instead of relative, it's working like I expected. Why is this happening?

EDIT: I'm sorry. I meant to ask about the height. I updated the question as necessary. I'm aware about $(window).width() and $(window).height(). That is not the point. I'd like to know why body loses it's height when it's set to relative positioning.

Comment: You should add a container div and set the width and height of that one to be 100%.

Comment: I'm getting the window width [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S5kLX/) even if i dont add any element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With position relative the document would get the height of the whole elements within the document when you use jquery and since you apply absolute position it will get the height of the document itself as if it is contained in 100% full height. Sorry, I'm unable to make you clear in my words.

But to solve the issue just add `overflow:hidden;` to the body and then check with jquery it will obviously get full height.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(document).width();` for getting the total width of a body or HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('window').width();
```

or

```
$('document').width();
```